# how to animate 3d plot given a rotation axis in mathematics

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

If given a rotation axis normalized, such as {1/Sqrt[3],1/Sqrt[3],1/Sqrt[3]}, and a 3d plot, for example,

`z[x_, y_] := Exp[-(Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]/Power[4, (3)^-1]) + 
    Power[4, (3)^-1]*Sqrt[1/2*(Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] + x)]];`

`Plot3D[2*z[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]`

I want to create an animation for this plot about the axis {1/Sqrt[3],1/Sqrt[3],1/Sqrt[3]} (could be any other arbitary one), and then export it as an animated gif. Would anyone please help? Many thanks.

**Edit**

I also left out one degree of freedom in specifying the rotation. Could any one please help, if also given the coordinate of a point which the rotational axis must pass, how to do the visualization/animation?
Thanks again.

Comment: I beg you to review your decision and accept Daniel's answer instead of mine. I copied the code there and just added the export feature, not a big deal. It's a shame to get 15 points just for copying and pasting. Thanks! –

Comment: @belisarius: i understood, and I would go with what you requested here. :) Initially I thought about this, and I thought yours is a complete solution. It'll be easier for people who come to read this post. But anyhow...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could do as below.

```
axis = {1, 1, 1};

Animate[
  Plot3D[2*z[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}] /. 
    gg : GraphicsComplex[___] :> Rotate[gg, theta, axis],
  {theta, 0., 2.*Pi}]
```

[image]

Daniel Lichtblau
Wolfram Research

Comment: @Daniel: thanks a lot. Do you happen to remember how to export the animation?

Comment: @Qiang To export is easier to make a Table[] with the plots and then Export["filename.gif", tableWithPlots]

Comment: @belisarius: could you please give a complete solution to do the export part?

Comment: @Daniel: I found during rotation, the origin is actually moving around. How to fix it?

Comment: @Qiang  I copied what Daniel did and completed for exporting.

Comment: @Qiang: The axis is not actually moving, but as the PlotRange changes during the animation, the whole thing wobbles a bit. I've placed some code in a new answer showing how to fix it.

Comment: @Simon yep. Getting these animations right sometimes is tricky. This one was easy.

Comment: @Simon The last one here was more difficult: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362498/curve-fitting-points-in-3d-space/4362773#4362773

Comment: @Simon: where is your new answer? :-)

Comment: @Qiang - I deleted it, since belisarius had already fixed the PlotRange. I thought I had also removed the comment... sorry!

Comment: @belisarius, +1 on your old 4362498 answer. Sometimes you put a crazy (read: more than the question deserves or the OP expects) amount of effort into these things! Not that I or they are complaining.

Comment: @belisarius: That reminds me - I can't believe your (really good) [understanding randomness](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956478/understanding-randomness/3956538#3956538) answer is up to 806 votes! That has to be a record...

Comment: @Simon Regarding the randomness answer, I guess most 101 courses are too boring and people tend to forget them. Then, a few years later, someone tells them the same using visually appealing examples and they realize the importance of the concept and the dangers of ignoring the basics. Its incredible score was a surprise for me too, mostly because my poor command of the English language drives me usually to write answers that either are very short or depict me as a simpleton.

Comment: @Simon @belisarius Thanks for fixing the wobbles. Probably just as well you didn't add a helicopter to the picture.

Comment: @Daniel The code was yours :D. I only add helicopters to questions without the Mma tag, because this community is too propense to scorn publicly on graphics exuberance :P

Comment: @balisarius, @Simon, @Daniel, please also see my edit where I also want to completely specify the rotational axis, here how to do the visualization? thanks a lot again.

Comment: @Qiang I beg you to review your decision and accept this answer instead of mine. I copied the code here and just added the export feature, not a big deal. It's a shame to get 15 points just for copying and pasting. Thanks!

Comment: @belisarius I'm always happy for a point gain, but I was surviving on what I had. At least, I think I was surviving...maybe best I check my pulse.

Comment: @Daniel If you need to analyze your pulse, Mma has wavelets now!

Comment: I'm running both @DanielLichtblau 's answer and Dr. belisarius' answer in Mathematica 11, and it seems to just produce an empty box.  Is it working in v11 for anyone else?

Comment: @billc Did you remember to define `z[x_,y_]`?

Answer (score 7):

Copying what Daniel did, just prepared for exporting.

```
axis = {1, 1, 1};
l = {-7, 7};

s = Table[

      Plot3D[2*z[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> {l, l, l}] /. 

      gg : GraphicsComplex[___] :> Rotate[gg, theta, axis], {theta, 0., 2. Pi}];

Export["c:\\test.gif", s]
```

[image]

The following parameters are available for the gif export (as per the docs):

```
"AnimationRepetitions" how many times the animation is played before stopping
"Background"           background color shown in transparent image regions 
"BitDepth"             bits used to represent each color channel in the file
"ColorMap"             color reduction palette, given as a list of color values
"GlobalColorMap"       default color palette for individual animation frames
"DisplayDurations"     display durations of animation frames, given in seconds
"ImageCount"           number of frames in an animated GIF
"ImageSize"            overall image size
"RawData"              array of color map indices
"Comments"             user comments stored in the file
```

I used "DisplayDurations" in the past, and it worked.

Comment: thanks a lot. I am just wondering whether there is an automatic way of choosing the PlotRange for this purpose. Sometimes, it is rather difficult to look at the graph to guesstimate the range.

Comment: @Daniel, @belisarius: it looks like that Animate produces very poor graphics when compared with the output animated gif. Did you notice the same effect? I am wondering why this is the case; maybe there is an improvement for Animate?

Comment: @Qiang Li: The reason for the gif being nicer is that the data is not computed along the way. Try `ListAnimate[s]` with s as above. There are options for frame-rate, etc.