# animate 3d plot with some further requirements in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I posted at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148491/how-to-animate-3d-plot-given-a-rotation-axis-in-mathematics) before, but I still could not solve the following problem completely. As an example:

```
{pA, pB, pC, pD} = {{0, 0, Sqrt[61/3]}, {Sqrt[7], 4*Sqrt[2/3], 0}, {0, -5*Sqrt[2/3], 0}, {-Sqrt[71], 4*Sqrt[2/3], 0}};
axis={1,0,0};pt={0,1,0};
plotPolygon[{a_, b_, c_}] := {Opacity[.4], Polygon[{a, b, c}]};
graph=Graphics3D[{plotPolygon[{pA, pB, pC}], plotPolygon[{pA, pB, pD}], 
            plotPolygon[{pB, pC, pD}], plotPolygon[{pA, pC, pD}]}, 
            Axes -> True, AxesOrigin->pt];
Animate[graph/.gg : Graphics3D[___] :> Rotate[gg, theta, axis], {theta, 0., 2.*Pi}]
```

[image]

I want to rotate along an axis `axis={1,0,0}` which passes the point `pt={0,1,0}`. But I don't know how to specify the point information. Also the rotation animation seems very chaotic in the sense that I would expect at least one point (in this case, the origin?) is not rotating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to first change the origin of vertices of your polygon, rotate, and translate back.  You can do this by hand

```
(RotationMatrix[theta,axis].(#-pt) + pt)& /@ {pA, pB, pC, pD}
```

Or, you can combine the transformations using [Composition](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Composition.html?q=Composition&lang=en)

```
Composition[
 AffineTransform[{RotationMatrix[theta,axis],pt}],TranslationTransform[-pt]
] /@ {pA, pB, pC, pD}
```

Or, you can take the previous composition and apply it directly to your `Graphics` object

```
GeometricTransformation[ <graphics>, Composition[ ... ]]
```

This [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/GeometricTransforms.html) gives a thorough list of what can be done.

**Edit**: Here's a working animation script

```
Animate[
  graph /. Graphics3D[prims__, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :> 
    Graphics3D[
      GeometricTransformation[prims,
        Composition[
          AffineTransform[{RotationMatrix[theta, axis], pt}],
          TranslationTransform[-pt]
        ]
      ],
      opts
    ], 
  {theta, 0., 2.*Pi}
]
```

There's a couple of things to note here.  First, `GeometricTransformation` only appears to work on the primitives themselves, so I had to split out the primitives from the options in `Graphics3D` via the rule `Graphics3D[prims__, opts : OptionsPattern[]]`.  Also, the transformation itself needs to be within `Animate` to use the local version of `theta`.

Comment: could you make the example I gave work? I tried, but still don't know how. thanks a lot.

Comment: One thing to add, `AffineTransform` does the translate back for us after the rotation, so I used it instead of doing it in 3 steps.