# Moving an AutoCad DXF solid along a 3D path in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, autocad

I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362498/curve-fitting-points-in-3d-space/4362773#4362773) and found belisarius' answer interesting. Wondering whether <s>he</s> someone can post <s>his</s>
 complete mma code and give some explanation. In general, my question is about how to achieve this kind of annimation/plotting behavior in mma. It looks amazing to me!

Many thanks.

Comment: Edited and opened the question to the world

Comment: @belisarius: Opened it to the world, then promptly smacked your solution down! :)

Comment: @Simon Yeah. I was working on it since Qiang left me a comment on the other question. We have all the rep business setup in order :)

Comment: @belisarius: A perfect plan! BTW, talking about the "rep business" I chucked 100rep down on the [default ColorData in Plot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399216/how-to-change-the-default-colordata-used-in-mathematicas-plot) question... since the problem's probably impossible (unless you work at WRI) I doubt that it will help things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please tell me if further explanation is needed.

```
x[t_] := {Cos@t, Sin@t, .1  t} /; t <= 3 Pi;
x[t_] := {Cos@t, Sin@t, .3 Pi  (4 - t/Pi)} /; t > 3 Pi;
plotRange = {{-110, 110}, {-110, 110}, {-10, 110}};
z1 = ParametricPlot3D[100 x[t], {t, 0, 4 Pi}, PlotRange -> plotRange];
hel = Import["ExampleData/helicopter.dxf.gz", 
   ViewPoint -> {10, 10, 10}, AlignmentPoint -> {80, 80, 80}];

zz = Table[
   Show[z1, 
    Graphics3D[
     Translate[Rotate[First[hel], t + Pi/2, {0, 0, 1}], 100 x[t]]], 
    PlotRange -> plotRange], {t, 0, 4 Pi, 4 Pi/15}];
Export["c:\\test.gif", zz, "DisplayDurations" -> .5]

(* Or
 Animate[Show[z1, 
   Graphics3D[
    Translate[Rotate[First[hel], t + Pi/2, {0, 0, 1}], 100 x[t]]], 
   PlotRange -> plotRange], {t, 0, 4 Pi}]
```

[image]

One could calculate the heli rotation using the curve derivatives. Too lazy to do it right now.

**Edit**

To comply with Sjoerd's home decoration rules:

[image]

Comment: You forgot to add this: `Sound[Play[
  Sin[50 t] (Sin[100 t] + Sin[140 t] + Sin[180 t]), {t, 0, 20}]]`

Comment: @Sjoerd This one is for your UFO movie in skeptics: `Sound[Play[
  Sin[5000 t] (Sin[100 t] + Sin[140 t] + Sin[180 t]), {t, 0, 5}]]`

Comment: @belisarius  ;-)  The stabilized movie was made using Mathematica's new image processing tools, BTW. It was a great learning project.

Comment: @Sjoerd I have been playing around with those tools too. You can do amazing things in a few steps. The performance is not very good, but they are a great sandbox for testing algorithms.

Comment: @belisarius I changed your animation.  If you do not approve, please roll back the edit.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You'd better use t+Pi instead.

Comment: @Sjoerd, what did I screw up this time? :)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Could we have a blue helicopter instead of a pink one? It doesn't match my carpet.

Comment: @Sjoerd @belisarius You guys are crazy!

Comment: Also, the blue one is slightly out of sync with mine.  Please fix it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard @belisarius ;-) It's all in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: @Mr. I synchronized mine with Saturn's rings fourth harmonic, which is of utmost importance to preserve the Ying balance in Sjoerd's home decoration initiative, as clearly indicated by his interventions in the skeptics discussion board.

Comment: @Sjoerd oh come on, what's the _worst_ that could happen? ... ... ... ;-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard A millstone bound to your leg, thrown in the lake? Or perhaps getting a job as PR guy for Stephen Wolfram.

Comment: @Sjoerd Hmmm ... How big is that millstone?

Comment: belisarius, anyone watching your edits without reading these comments is going to be really confused. lol

Comment: Look mama, the helicopter got a friend!